# Sitecore CD Server Trying to Access /sitecore folder

Tags: security, content-delivery, iis

Not sure why Sitecore CD server trying to access **/sitecore** folder (attached screenshot).  Enabled **SwitchMasterToWeb.config** file and disabled anonymous IIS access to the **/sitecore/shell** folder and did all from this article
[Sitecore - Restrict Access](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/restrict-access-to-the-client.html). Not sure from where/why CD server calling this URL. Any thoughts/suggestions?

[image: browser console]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Developer Tools` in your browser and reload the page.

Check the `Network` tab and find the script you're interested in.

In the `Initiator` column you will see which page or script is trying to use that `/sitecore/...` javascript.

[image]

If it's requested from the page, check the source of your page. If it's requested from another javascript, check what is calling for that other javascript.

Comment: it's showing our domain.com/:157, when I try to click it's going to home page. I checked main template file and nothing there.